# View Postgres connection string

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, connection

Is there a way I can view the connection string used by the client to connect to my Postgres instance?

Problem:
I am connecting to Postgres via jasper and I am setting `prepareThreshold=0` in the connection string to disable prepared statements. I see that it's not being honoured for some reason. So I would like to confirm that jasper is actually passing the setting in the connection string correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the database server only for information it has.

`prepareThreshold` is a setting of the JDBC driver, and the database has no knowledge about it.

You can cast the `java.sql.Connection` to an `org.postgresql.PGConnection` and use the `getPrepareThreshold()` method to get the desired information.